# JSON returning undefined values

Tags: javascript, json

I have a problem with a `json` output values returning undefined.

JSON:

```
[ { ID: 2, user: 'ngx.daniel', password: 'password', admin: 'F' } ]
```

CODE:

```
console.log(res);
res = JSON.stringify(res);
console.log(res);
var user = {};
user.user = res.user;
user.password = res.password;
user.admin = res.admin;
console.log(user);
```

OUTPUT:

```
[ RowDataPacket { ID: 2, user: 'ngx.daniel', password: 'password', admin: 'F' } ]
[ { ID: 2, user: 'ngx.daniel', password: 'password', admin: 'F' } ]
{ user: undefined, password: undefined, admin: undefined }
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify` returns a string.  Why do you expect a string to have a `user` property?

Comment: @turbopipp: That will make no difference.

Comment: JSON likes strings inside the objects, from what I remember

Comment: Your JSON syntax is wrong. It should be `[ { "ID": 2, "user": "ngx.daniel", "password": "Root_!$@#", "admin": "F" } ]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things. If this is your json:

```
[ RowDataPacket { ID: 2, user: 'ngx.daniel', password: 'password', admin: 'F' } ]
```

you dont need to stringify it. When you stringify it you turn your object into a string. you then try to access attributes of a string, which it doesnt have.
1 - Remove the stringify
2 - Thats an array thats being returned with a RowPacketData object, which is also invalid json.
3 - To access an object in an array you need to first access the index. So it should really be something like

(if `res` = `[ { ID: 2, user: 'ngx.daniel', password: 'Root_!$@#', admin: 'F' }]`)

```
var user = {};
user.user = res[0].user;
user.password = res[0].password;
user.admin = res[0].admin;
```

Answer (score 0):

The response can apparently consist of multiple items (`RowDataPackets`). You can get the first via index 0. And there is no need to stringify the response:

```
console.log(res);
var user = {};
user.user = res[0].user;
user.password = res[0].password;
user.admin = res[0].admin;
console.log(user);
```

Which prints

> Object { user="ngx.daniel",  password="Root_!$@#",  admin="F"}