# undefined values returned using json in datatables.net

Tags: php, jquery, json, datatables

**Intro**: I am making a server-side datatables using ajax in datatables.net that can be found below:
https://databasetable-net.000webhostapp.com/

**Errors:**
The data in the table returns as 'undefined' instead of the actual data (click above link to see). There are no errors in the console or in the datatables dubug tracer which is why I am now seeking help.

**Index.php**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "server.php",
                "type": "POST"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data" : "id"},
                { "data" : "first_name"},
                { "data" : "last_name"},
                { "data" : "position"},
                { "data" : "date"},
                { "data" : "updated"},
            ],
});
 }); 
$(document).ready(function(){ $.getJSON('server.php', function(data){
    var employee_data=''; 
    $.each(data, function(key,value){ 
    employee_data+='<tr>';
    employee_data+='<td>'+value.id+'</td>';
    employee_data+='<td>'+value.first_name+'</td>';
    employee_data+='<td>'+value.last_name+'</td>';
    employee_data+='<td>'+value.position+'</td>';
    employee_data+='<td>'+value.date+'</td>';
    employee_data+='<td>'+value.updated+'</td>';
 }); 
    $('#example').append(employee_data);
    }); 
}); 
  </script>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Updated</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
             <th>ID</th>
                <th>First name</th>
                <th>Last name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Updated</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>

<?php
$records = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM employees");
$totalData= $records->num_rows;
$totalFiltered=$totalData;
$data=array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($records)) { 
    $subdata=array();
    $subdata[]=$row[0]; //id
    $subdata[]=$row[1]; 
    $subdata[]=$row[2]; 
    $subdata[]=$row[3]; 
    $subdata[]=$row[4]; 
    $subdata[]=$row[5]; 
    $data[]=$subdata;
}

$requestData= $_REQUEST;
//https://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/94864/

$json_data = array(
                  "draw" => intval(isset($_GET['draw'])), 
                  "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalData ), 
                  "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ),
                  "data"            => $data //How To Retrieve This Data
                 );

echo json_encode($json_data);  
?>
```

**Server.php**

```
$table = 'employees';

// Table's primary key
$primaryKey = 'id';

// Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
// The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
// parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple
// indexes
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'id', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'first_name', 'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'last_name',  'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 'db' => 'position',   'dt' => 3 ),
    array( 'db' => 'date',     'dt' => 4 ),
     array( 'db' => 'updated',     'dt' => 5 ),
);

// SQL server connection information
$sql_details = array(
    'user' => 'id3741634_username',
    'pass' => 'password',
    'db'   => 'id3741634_database',
    'host' => 'localhost'
);

/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP
 * server-side, there is no need to edit below this line.
 */

require( 'ssp.class.php' );

echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
```

**Conclusion:**
Sorta like this article but I did not use stringify:[JSON returning undefined values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32683266/json-returning-undefined-values)

I mostly used this article for the foundation of my code.
https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side

I am unsure how to go about this issue with no errors and little JSON experience. I suspect my issue maybe something minor. Please let me know if I can make any changes to improve my post. Thanks!

Comment: I have been focused on getting the data to appear (which is the hardest part) so originally I had in the HTML to get a foundation. I suppose I should now remove the HTML (we'll see what happens).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Get rid of that initial `$.getJSON()` call manually inserting html. When you use datatables with ajax sourced data, you need to let datatables build the html.  As it is you are inserting rows (and an implied `<tbody>` *after* the `<tfoot>`) which is also problematic.

2) Your ajax calls including the initial `$.getJSON()` are all returning 0 records, and and empty array.  That's why all of the cell values are undefined.  those rows actually should not exist ... but regardless of that, your `Server.php` scripts is not returning any rows.

If you try changing the `Show XX Entries` select menu at the top left corner and you will see the table get updated properly with server side data.  Notice how it now shows (correctly) **`"No data available in table"`**.

Comment: Ok thanks for responding. I am assuming delete the "$.getJSON('server.php', function(data)" part (or the whole section?).

Comment: And yes I know something is probably wrong with the encode json part but I wanted a second opinion first without saying anything. I am suspecing the code as follows belongs in the server.php part and not the index? I realized it is not triggering properly. 
                  "draw" => intval(isset($_GET['draw'])), 
                  "recordsTotal"    => intval( $totalData ), 
                  "recordsFiltered" => intval( $totalFiltered ),
                  "data"            => $data //How To Retrieve This Data
                 ); echo json_encode($json_data);

Comment: yes - datatables should handle everything relating to building the table body.  as for why there's no data being returned you'll need to check you query and database

Comment: as far as I can see, the response is fine.  it's properly structured and the draw count is getting updated.  you just need to return something other than an empty array

Comment: Ok thanks for help. I might post on datables.net/forums to see why nothing is getting displayed on the server-side. I followed the instructions step by step so as you, I am puzzled. I tried adding the $.getJson part because I saw nothing wrong with the server.php

Comment: You already have an answer to that question: *Nothing is displayed because no data was returned*.   That is your answer.  What you should be asking is why is nothing being returned?  And that would only be something you can ascertain by examining the queries you are running and the rows in your database..

Comment: Yes that is what I meant. Positive update, I got things to appear in the array but not in the table itself: raw":0,"recordsTotal":2,"recordsFiltered":2,"data":[["1","Robert","Mueller","Lawyer","2018-04-05","2018-04-05"],["23","Robert","Mueller","Lawyer","2018-04-05","2018-04-05"]]}

Comment: You need to return a json object (associative array) in that case with the column names as keys - either that or lose the whole `"columns":` declaration in your table init.  You are only supplying a plain array but datatables is looking for keys since you have specified a data attribute.  This is going way beyond your initial question.  If my answer helped you please mark it as correct.

Comment: Removing the columns section worked. sure I can mark as answer for sure. Thanks for help!

Comment: I just realized the columns do not sort on click. I am doing research into this matter. If you have a link with help by chance that would be great.

Comment: When you do server side processing you are responsible for everything.  That includes row counts, filtering, ordering.  everything.  If you have fewer than a couple thousand rows, it's often much easier to just use ajax data source with **client side** processing instead of server side.  I have a few tables where I use server side processing and though it pays off in terms of performance when you are dealing with 100,000 rows, it's quite a bit more work to create the back end scripts

Comment: I should mention that I've never used that ssp library and looks like it handles a lot of those details for you.  But I still recommend ajax with client side processing as the best option for tables < 2500 rows

Comment: Yes I have a HTML client-side and self-made database already made. I am having to make a server-side table for training for my employer. I might be able to done now though (we'll see what they say). I found the ssp.class.php easier than the editor.php large-zip-package (though, I may take time to build one of those too).